# Can I Use Typed Factory Facility to Return Implementation Based on (enum) Parameter?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

Not sure if this is possible or not.

I need to return the correct implementation of a service based on an enum value.  So the hand-coded implementation would look something like:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  One,
  Two
}    

public class MyFactory
{
  public ITypeIWantToCreate Create(MyEnum type)
  {
    switch (type)
    {
       case MyEnum.One
           return new TypeIWantToCreate1();
           break;
       case MyEnum.Two
           return new TypeIWantToCreate2();
           break;
       default:
           return null;       
    }    
  }
}
```

The implementations that are returned have additional dependencies which will need to be injected via the container, so a hand-rolled factory won't work.

Is this possible, and if so what would the registration look like?

Comment: What's wrong with registering that factory in your container, and instead of doing `new Type1`, just calling back into the container?

Comment: I don't want to resolve directly from the container--I won't have access to the container at this point in the code.

Comment: Make that factory part of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) of your application (and let it depend on an `IMyFactroy` interface that is part of the application). In that case it is fine to access the container ([this is *not* the Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorRolesVsMechanics.aspx)). Just inject the container into the constructor of the factory and you're fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If registering your component into the container specifying the enum value as component id is an option, you may considering this approach too

```
 public class ByIdTypedFactoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
 {
      protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
      {
            if (method.Name == "GetById" && arguments.Length > 0 && arguments[0] is YourEnum)
            {
                 return (string)arguments[0].ToString();
            }

            return base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
      }
}
```

than ByIdTypedFactoryComponentSelector will be used as Selector for your Typed factory

```
public enum YourEnum
{
    Option1
}

public IYourTypedFactory
{
    IYourTyped GetById(YourEnum enumValue)
}


container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register
(       
    Component.For<ByIdTypedFactoryComponentSelector>(),

    Component.For<IYourTyped>().ImplementedBy<FooYourTyped>().Named(YourEnum.Option1.ToString()),

    Component.For<IYourTypedFactory>()
    .AsFactory(x => x.SelectedWith<ByIdTypedFactoryComponentSelector>())
    .LifeStyle.Singleton,

    ...
```

Comment: what if TypeIWantToCreate1 or TypeIWantToCreate2 required parameters? The first one was dedicated to find the Component and the others would be injected to the Component instance?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is possible.  Take a look at this:

[Example](http://kozmic.pl/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/)

You will need to create an ITypedFactoryComponentSelector implementation to resolve the call, and register it in the container to only resolve the calls for the classes you are interested in.